# Does Altium Designer 14 work with Windows 8?

Tags: altium

I have a AD 09 license from my school, and they said it would not work on a W8 pc. Now I am in process of getting a new laptop. Since most laptops come with W8, I am wondering if I will be able to run Altium if I upgrade it too. Does anybody here have any experience?

I tried searching, but "Altium designer windows 8" doesn't really bring up anything, for or against.

Another option is to install W7 on the laptop, but I am not sure if all the drivers are available for anything else than W8. (Although I think some W8 pro computers come with a downgrade option)

Comment: You should probably just ask Altium themselves?

Comment: @dext0rb I figured out this would be faster and maybe help others with the same problem through Google. Also some companies have a reputation of not being interested if you are a student (not going to pay big money). I have no experience with contacting Altium though.

Comment: The Altium forums are actually a nice source if you're dealing with such questions and do not need to rely on a "official" answer (which will probably be "no"). Yet, access to the forums is limited to customers.

Comment: Perhaps consider something like VMWare? Run Windows 7 inside Windows 8. Should have less issues as far as drivers are concerned.

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky That's a good point. But hopefully it will work natively, as Tom L. said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using altium designer 14.1 and its working fine in windows 8.

Answer (score 4):

I can only say that 13.3.4 does. And I see no reason why it should be different for 14. I do NOT use the nanoboard or any other hardware so I cannot say about that.

Comment: Just tested 14.x (don't remember exactely which one): Works as well.